# Sqoop export from HDFS to Teradata

Tags: hadoop

In sqoop export fro HDFS to teradata, i am facing following error how to fix the issue
INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1435465700866_0006_m_000001_2, Status : FAILED
Error: com.teradata.connector.common.exception.ConnectorException: Batch insert job failed

Command i am using is

```
sqoop export --connect jdbc:teradata://x.x.x.x/DATABASE=university -username dbc -password dbc --input-fields-terminated-by ',' -table <table_name> --num-mappers 100  -export-dir <path>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to export the same table multiple times. Teradata causes issues when duplicate data is exported to it repeatedly.

I also had a issue with teradata cause i tried to export same table multiple times and it started throwing errors.

Please try to reinstall teradata or try making some space in your teradata database.